# macos - CFStringGetLength EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) crash

Tags: macos, core-foundation

I have the following code:

```
char *get_string_property_2(IOHIDDeviceRef device, CFStringRef prop)
{

    CFStringRef str = IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(device, prop);

    if(str)
    {
         CFIndex str_len = CFStringGetLength(str);
         ...

    }

    ...
}
```

sometimes (not always) I get a crash in `CFStringGetLength` with the following log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff770083a8

Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff88e22097 objc_msgSend + 23
1   libtobii_usb.dylib              0x00000001081c4f72 get_string_property_2 + 130 (macosx.c:99)
2   serviced                        0x00000001081a5fad device_removed_callback + 285 (daemond_mac.c:614)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ae35899 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ae3572a _pthread_start + 137
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ae39fc9 thread_start + 13
```

How can I fix this? I am checking if str is NULL or not before calling `CFStringGetLength` apparently it is not enough.

**EDIT:**

I am still getting this crash, always in the same place.

If it is a bad pointer why doesn't crash one line above in `IOHIDDeviceGetProperty`??

Is there any other way that I can get the length of a `CFStringRef`?

I suspect that there is a bug in the api.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts. First, IOKit's lifecycles have always been tricky for me. There are many areas where you have to be super careful about retaining objects, which are "consumed" by API calls.

Second, your crash is happening in device_removed_callback, which further makes me suspect that some object is getting deallocated behind the scenes, but you aren't noticing until the callback occurs.

Bad pointers aren't always null, and are frequently pointing to memory that is mapped into your process, but doesn't point to what you think it should. This is commonly called a dangling pointer, and is very, very common. Often also hard to debug.

I bet that this is due to an object lifecycle issue in another area of your IOKit code, and manifesting here. Try using NSZombies (which might also work for CF objects, I cannot recall). Also, double-check that the areas which are registering for device notifications are doing the right thing with memory management. I've encountered many bugs in that area.